# Opencart show sidebar in checkout page

Tags: php, opencart

I am new to [opencart](http://www.opencart.com/). Here as per my layout I have a left sidebar where I can see all the product category. I have used the sidebar in home page and product details page and it is looking fine. Like this I want to show the sidebar in checkout Page . So can someone kindly tell me how to show the sidebar in checkout page?

Answer (score 1):

Login to your admin area then navigate to:

```
Extensions > Modules
```

Then click on the `Edit` link (under the actions column) next to `Category` module name.

Click the `Add Module` button and select `Checkout` as your layout and `Content Left` as the position.

Make sure that you've enabled it and click `Save`. Refresh your page and you should then see the category list on your checkout page.

Hope that helps!!